# register and login page use https asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I have a webhost with Godaddy and I brought an ssl certificate with my domain. Is there an simple way to have the login.aspx page and the register.aspx page go to https? I don't want to have to explicitly say redirect("https://domain/login.aspx). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Manual redirect is probably the most reliable way. Why it doesn't suit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to modify those pages with the following code (redirects to https if not running locally, and not a secure connection):

```
if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Often the simplest solution is best, but if you wanna get nuts...

You could write an HTTP module to make sure a list of specific pages are redirected to SSL.

```
public class EnsureSslModule : IHttpModule
{
    private static readonly string[] _pagesToEnsure = new[] { "login.aspx", "register.aspx" };

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
    }

    public void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var context = application.Context;

        var url = context.Request.RawUrl;

        if (!context.Request.IsSecureConnection 
                && _pagesToEnsure.Any(page => url.IndexOf(page, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1))
        {
            var builder = new UriBuilder(url);

            builder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;

            context.Response.Redirect(builder.Uri
                .GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Port,
                               UriFormat.UriEscaped), true);
        }
    }
}
```